# Proof of $p \in \mathbb{R}_{+}$ then $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n^{p}} = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, proof-writing, proof-explanation, solution-verification

I want to show the following:

Let $p \in \mathbb{R}_{+}$,  then $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n^{p}} = 0 $.

My proof is the following.

From the Archimedean property of real numbers $\forall p > 0$, $\exists m \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $m>p$.
Then:
\begin{equation}
0 < \frac{1}{n^{p}} = \left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^{p} < \left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^{m}
\end{equation}

Now assume that: $\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^{m} > \epsilon $  $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$. Then it follows that:

$n <\frac{1}{\epsilon^{m}}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

But this means that $\mathbb{N}$ is bounded above and this is absurd. Then $\exists n_{0}\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{1}{n^{p}} < \epsilon$, $\forall n > n_{0}$.

I'm not sure about the logical steps involved in the proof. Can you tell me if there is something wrong with it?

Thanks!

Comment: Why did you need $m$? You could have kept using $p$ in your argument

Comment: The first statement is wrong: let $p=1/2$.

Comment: $\left(\frac12\right)^2>\left(\frac12\right)^3$.

Comment: You are all right. A very stupid mistake... I have to fix the proof! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

For p$\ge$1, n<nᵖ for all natural numbers n $\ge$ 2. So, 0<1/nᵖ<1/n , now by Archimeadian property, for any $\epsilon$ > 0, 0<1/n< $\epsilon$ for all n$\ge$N ,for some natural number N. Hence, 1/nᵖ <$\epsilon$ for all n$\ge$ N.
For 0<p<1, if possible let, 1/nᵖ > G for some positive real G, holds for all natural numbers n, then n<1/$G^{1/p}$ , but this is a contradiction to archimeadian property because Archimeadian property says that for any real x>0, there always exist a natural number n such that n>x. So, our assumption is wrong . Hence , 1/nᵖ <$\epsilon$ for all n$\ge$ N(for some natural number N).
So,for every $p \in \mathbb{R}_{+}$ , $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n^{p}} = 0$

Comment: You should use mathjax.

Comment: @AmanPandey Is there a way to fix my initial proof? Thanks!

Comment: @MatteoGardini see my answer.

Comment: Why I am devoted, I still don't know! Please tell me @ devotees ,

Comment: If someone can't accept it, it's ok! But while you devote a answer, then you must have to say, what's the wrong things in mathematical logic! Please don't missuse your power!

Comment: At least we are here for help!

Comment: @Subhajit Yes! You are right. Probably they devoted because you didn't use mathjax.Well! Your proof looks good to me (+1).

Comment: @Sunhajit One more thing if the proof is valid for $p\geq 1$ Then why you mentioned in last line for every $p\in \Bbb{R}_+$ ,$\operatorname{ lim}\frac{1}{n^p}=0 $ as $n\to \infty$

Comment: No, it's valid for all positive real,, please see the second paragraph.I prove it for all real p

Comment: I couldn't find any proof which is valid for $p\in \Bbb{R}_+$.

Comment: For 0<p<1 I prove it by using contradiction against archimeadian prop.

Comment: @Subhajit Yup${}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 0):

Let $a_n=\frac{1}{n^p}$, we need to show that $\operatorname{lim}a_n=0$. For given $\epsilon> 0$. Let us choose $N\in \Bbb{N}$ such that $N >( \frac{1}{\epsilon})^\frac{1}{p}$(by the Archimedean property)so $N>(\frac{1}{\epsilon})^\frac{1}{p}$ for $p\geq 1$. Then,  if$n \geq N$. Then, $n\geq N$ implies $\frac{1}{n}\leq\frac{1}{N}<\epsilon^\frac{1}{p}$. Consequently, if $n\geq N$, then

$$|a_n-0|=|\frac{1}{n^p}-0|=\frac{1}{n^p}<\epsilon$$ for $p\geq 1$.

Comment: You can't take epsilon fixed, then how can you do arbitrarily run it close to 0,                                                        Next thing, if 1/n<=1/N, only for p>=1, 1/nᵖ<= 1/Nᵖ possible! Check that,

Comment: @Subhajit  I edited. Thanks!